# How can I get this Select to update onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I have a react-select input that populates countries from a json file which is in a form to be submitted. When a selection is made, the select won't populate with the selection but still sends the value of the selection on submit as expected. But how can I get it to populate the field with the selection as well? I'm new to React, thanks!

COUNTRIES.json file

```
[
 {
  "value": "Afghanistan"
 },
 {
"value": "Åland Islands"
 }
]
```

events.js file

```
import countries from "../utils/COUNTRIES.json";
import Select from "react-select";

const EventsPage = () => {


const [ country, setCountry ] = useState("")

const onCountryChange = obj => {
setCountry(obj.value)
}



return (
 <Layout>


<Select
name="countries"
id="countries"
placeholder="Select a country"
options={countries}
onChange = {onCountryChange}
value={country}
getOptionLabel={(option) => option.value}
getOptionSelected={(option) => option.value}        
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing it to something along these lines:

```
import countries from "../utils/COUNTRIES.json";
import Select from "react-select";

const EventsPage = () => {


const [ country, setCountry ] = useState("")

return (
 <Layout>


<Select
name="countries"
id="countries"
placeholder="Select a country"
options={countries.map(x => x.value)}
onChange={setCountry}
value={country}
/>
```

There is probably a mismatch between the options passed and the current value.